# Proper input for initialize function in UniswapV3Pool

Tags: uniswapv3

I want to initialize a pool programmatically using `initialize()` from the `UniswapV3Pool.sol`, after a lot of research I've found the `encodeSqrtRatioX96` function from the SDK. What happens if when I call it, it returns an array like this:

`JSBI(4) [ 191603664, 144497175, 920951055, 2023, sign: false ]`

The `sqrtPrice[0]` isn't a valid input for `initialize`. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

That is for the sqrtPrice**Ratio**  which is different from what you want

[image: NFTmanager create and initialize function]

So you need to get the sqrtPrice

```
                  Price of token 0 in value of token 1 (ex usdc/eth pool price)
let PriceToSqrt0 = new BN(0.000752976132445465)

                  Sqrt that price
let PriceToSqrt1 = PriceToSqrt0.sqrt()

                  Prices are in a Q96 format so multiply by 2^96
                  Then you will have to adjust for decimals 10^token0 Decimals
let PriceToSqrt = PriceToSqrt1.multipliedBy( 2 ** 96 ) * ( 10**6 ); (usdc decimals)
```